# Constraining foreign key to a specific instance of a model

Tags: python, sql, django, web

I have two instances of a model 'Product'. In the admin I upload two images to each one. When the images are called on their respective pages instead of the two, all four images are served to each page. How can I restrict the images to their proper products without them spilling into the wrong ones?

I have this relationship in my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

class Image(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def productpage(request, product_image_id):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    image_list = Image.objects.all()
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_image_id)
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=product_image_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {
        'product': product, 'image': image, 
        'product_list' : product_list, 'image_list':image_list
```

TEMPLATE

```
     {% for image in image_list %}      
<div id ="{{ image.image_id }}"class="numbers"><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="slide"></div>
     {% endfor %}
     }
```

I'm getting this result on both product pages, which returns all 4 images, when there should only be 2.

```
<div id ="one"class="numbers"><img src="/media/image/red1.jpg" alt="slide"></div>

<div id ="two"class="numbers"><img src="/media/image/red2.png" alt="slide"></div>

<div id ="one"class="numbers"><img src="/media/image/blue1.jpg" alt="slide"></div>

<div id ="two"class="numbers"><img src="/media/image/blue2.png" alt="slide"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting `image_list` which is all images, you can use `product` and get images only for that. You can do that in template itself using `product.image_set.all()` as

```
{% for image in product.image_set.all %}      
<div id ="{{ image.image_id }}"class="numbers"><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="slide"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: An extra tip: if you add a `related_name` to the foreign key field, you can change the default reverse relation name that Django generates ("image_set" in this case). So `product_image=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images')` means you can use `product.images.all()` instead of `product.image_set.all()`. You can often make it look nicer this way.